# How to change the owner in Linux directory

Tags: 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, linux-headers

Can someone please assist with this case. I have a folder called media. I need to change the owner for that directory.

drwxr-xr-x.   2 **root**         **root**    6 Jun 21  2021 media

**sudo chown prod media** then it got changed to prod.

drwxr-xr-x.   2 **prod**         **root**    6 Jun 21  2021 media

But here i have another root, that one also needs to be change to PROD.

Please explain for this attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"another root" is the group.

With

```
sudo chown prod media
```

you change the owner to `prod`.

With

```
sudo chown prod:prod media
```

you can change also the group to `prod`.

```
sudo chown :prod media
```

would only change the group.